# No ICE candidates generated when I run my local webRTC application on google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I have a basic webRTC application that supports video/audio communication and file sharing between two peers, The app runs as intended when I open it on Mozilla Firefox but when I run it on Google Chrome the **onicecandidate** returns null

My RTCPeerConnection

```
        myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
```

Setting up the peer connection

```
myConnection.createOffer().then(offer => {
    currentoffer = offer
    myConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
})
    .then(function () {
        myConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
            console.log(event.candidate);

            if (event.candidate) {
                send({
                    type: "candidate",
                    candidate: event.candidate
                });
            }
        };
        send({
            type: "offer",
            offer: currentoffer
        });
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
        alert("Problem with creating offer. " + reason);
    });
```

On Mozilla Firefox you can see in the console log all the ICE candidates that are collected on each "onicecandidate" event

[image: Firefox output]

On Chrome the output is null
[image: Chrome output]

Comment: I ran into the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

You should pass options object when calling `createOffer()` method, e.g.:

```
myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

var mediaConstraints = {
    'offerToReceiveAudio': true,
    'offerToReceiveVideo': true    
};

myConnection.createOffer(mediaConstraints).then(offer => {
        currentoffer = offer
        myConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    })
    ...// the rest of you code goes here
```

Alternatively, you can specify `RTCRtpTransceiver` before creating an offer:

```
myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

myConnection.addTransceiver("audio");
myConnection.addTransceiver("video");

myConnection.createOffer().then(offer => {
        currentoffer = offer
        myConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    })
    ...// the rest of you code goes here
```

Sources:
[WebRTC 1.0](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#method-extensions)
[MDN RTCPeerConnection.createOffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer)
[MDN RTCPeerConnection.addTransceiver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTransceiver)
Example -- [GitHub](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/c30661ef8c8b27e1daedbd7439fa98c53c10a43f/webrtc/legacy/RTCPeerConnection-createOffer-offerToReceive.html#L29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass STUN/TURN servers when create a peer connection.

Otherwise you will only local candidates and hence will be able to connect locally only

```
var STUN = {
    'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
};

var iceServers = 
{
    iceServers: [STUN]
};

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
```

Comment: Yes I understand, but I use my application locally over LAN and I do not need to utilize a STUN server.